# Change templates based on path alias

Tags: 7, theming, path-aliases

What is the easiest way to select a template based on path alias. For example, if I have the following URLs:

http://www.example.com/mydirectory/page1
http://www.example.com/mydirectory/page2
http://www.example.com/mydirectory/page3

How would I go about creating a template for all of the pages in *mydirectory*? I should also add that using content type to theme these pages is not an option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add some logic in a `hook_preprocess_page()` implementation that checks the alias, and adds theme hook suggestions if the path matches, e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $alias_parts = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());

  if (count($alias_parts) && $alias_parts[0] == 'mydirectory') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__mycustomtemplate';
  }
}
```

Then if you create a `page--mycustomtemplate.tpl.php` file in your theme, and clear the cache, any pages with an alias beginning `mydirectory/` will use that new file instead of the standard `page.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually easier than that using [drupal_match_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7) which is how the blocks module works out whether a block should be displayed on a page or not:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (drupal_match_path(drupal_get_path_alias(), 'mydirectory/*')) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__mycustomtemplate';
  }
}
```