# custom template file based on form type

Tags: theming

I'm using Omega's sub-theme *creativpink*. I put my site on web for testing purpose. Basically I want to customize page-user-reset page (*user-pass-reset* is form id). Now I click *Request new password* link enter my mail id to send password reset link. When I click on that link from my mail it redirects to page-user-reset page and it shows the following information:

### Site Name

- Home

#### Reset password

- This is a one-time login for *username* and will expire on Fri, 11/01/2013 - 20:41.
- Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.
- This login can be used only once.
  Login(button)

Powered by Drupal

Currently it includes header, breadcrum, content and footer regions. But I want only content region and the *user password reset* form inside content region. So I would like to write a template file based on this *user-pass-reset* form. Guide me what I want to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a `page--user--reset.tpl.php` template in your theme directory alongside any other page reset templates and just include the `content` region inside there.  More information [about template and theme hook suggestions can be found here](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) (or at least after drupal.org comes back from its upgrade :) but the basic idea is to override the internal path of `user/reset/../..` and Drupal is smart enough to ignore the rest of the path and just use the template given the base here.

Comment: I printed only content region in page--user--reset.tpl.php file. When I checked on my server I could see all the regions andI cannot read the drupal's template and theme hook suggestion page right now.

Comment: With drupal.org now back up, I will also assume you then cleared your theme registry / cache and it worked since you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's worked for me. Also I referred to the [Change templates based on path alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39908/change-templates-based-on-path-alias) link here. I did some modification to my `MYTHEME_preprocess_user_reset_page()`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_reset_page() {
  $alias_parts = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());
  // dpm($alias_parts);
  if (count($alias_parts) && $alias_parts[1] == 'reset') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__user__reset';
  }
}
```

Then in `page--user--reset.tpl.php` file I include only title and content of the page. Thank you so much and Clive too.