# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare THEMENAME_preprocess_page()

Tags: theming

In D7, we have two copies of the same [Bootstrap Agency](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_agency) base theme modified to show on different URLs using ThemeKey.

This works, but whenever a new module is installed, the site crashes and we see the following in the Apache error log:

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare bootstrap_agency_preprocess_page() (previously declared in /sites/all/themes/bootstrap_agency_minimal/template.php:13) in /sites/all/themes/bootstrap_agency/template.php on line 13`

This is actually a very similar issue to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97439/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-mytheme-preprocess-page) , I just couldn't comment on the above and [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive)'s answer wasn't all that clear to me. Is it better to merge the two functions or rename one of them - as the 2nd answer suggests? And what does merging entail?

Comment: Is there a bootstrap_agency_preprocess_page function inside of template.php in bootstrap_agency_minimal/template.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function names in template.php have to be prefixed with themename_function. At the same time, you cannot have a function declared twice.

`bootstrap_agency_preprocess_page()` should exist once in bootstrap_agency/template.php, and the other should be `bootstrap_agency_minimal_preprocess_page()` in bootstrap_agency_minimal/template.php.

If you do not need to do any override, and the one theme is a subtheme, you can simply omit it from template.php. Otherwise, you would need to copy the function code in and amend what you need to amend.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! We've already tried this is an experiment and it worked. Good to know it's a proper solution and hot a hack that would break something elsewhere.