# Create Drupal 7 page specific tpl files without using node ID's

Tags: 7, theming

i know you can crate custom tpl files for a specific page by doing the following:

html--node-999.tpl.php

But this doesnt work well if the node-id is going to change when switching environments or migrating stuff. What is the file naming convention for drupal 7 tpl's that are URL Path specific?

Comment: I would suggest that if you need to do this you haven't been specific enough with your content types. I would create a new content type for this specific template.

I'm also curious why you need a different html.tpl.php for different nodes?

Comment: its actually for a one off page that doesnt have to do with any other content type. which is why i think a tpl file specific to this would be fine.

Comment: Would Context help? i.e. use a path to set the context and take an appropriate action

Answer (score 1):

Happened upon this old question that didn't have a completely legit answer.

In short, you can set up templates based on path by using the formulae...

```
page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php
```

Put simply, if you want a specific page template for a custom page with a url of `support`, you would create a template named

```
page--support.tpl.php
```

or `support/contact` would be

```
page--support--contact.tpl.php
```

Of course you can and probably should use the `node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php` pattern if you are dealing with node pages.  But creating a template based on path is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **page--[path].tpl.php** or **node--[path].tpl.php** template name schema that will let you create a url-specific template, but you can do it through a [pre-process function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/39912/45675).