# Override tpl for custom menu page

Tags: theming, routes

I have created a custom menu with hook menu `booking/%/reschedule` and where % is nid of bookings ( content type ), I want to override tpl file for this page in my theme. I tried with `page--booking--%--reschedule.tpl.php` but its not working.

Comment: you want to override template for a specific content type.??

Comment: Want to override tpl for this menu page not for content type

Comment: Is would be the node id then booking--123--reschedule.tpl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this function in your `template.php` file, which is located in your theme (untested):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $alias_parts = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());

  if (count($alias_parts) && $alias_parts[0] == 'booking' && $alias_parts[2] == 'reschedule') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__bookingtemplate';
  }
}
```

Then you can create a new template file which is called `page--bookingtemplate.tpl.php` and after clearing the cache, it should work.

Credits to Clive for [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39908/change-templates-based-on-path-alias?answertab=active#answer-39912) post.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a menu by adding code in your file

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_links__system_MENUNAME_menu($variables) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
  }
  return $output;
}
?>
```